# Verificar se tem numero com isNaN nao funciona

Tags: javascript, angular

Gostaria de saber se a minha URL tem número (parâmetro de ID).

recebo isto:

```
rota = "/pessoa/editar/5";
```

apos o substring

```
rota = "/pessoa/editar";
```

```
validarRota(rota)
{
  if(!isNaN(rota))
  {
    rota = rota.substring(0, rota.lastIndexOf("/"));
  }
}
```

Mas nao entra no `if` do `isNaN`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Utilizo Angular 8.2

Comment: ao usar `!isNaN` vc quer verificar se é um número. Para verificar quando não é um número, retire o `!`.

Comment: Cara, o Sam está correto, você está negando o retorno da função incorretamente.

Comment: A função `isNaN` não serve para verificar se tem número. Ela serve para verificar se é ou não um número.

Comment: entao, sem o `!`, em outras rotas que nao tem numero ele tambem esta entrando no if, como por exemplo `pessoa/lista` fica `pessoa`

Comment: Assumindo que esse `5` é um parâmetro da rota, não seria melhor usar `ActivatedRoute` e verificar se o parâmetro está lá (e caso esteja, vc vê se somente ele é um número, sem precisar verificar a rota inteira)?

Comment: Teste `isNaN('/pessoa/editar/5')` e `isNaN('/pessoa/editar')`, ambos retornam `true`. Isso quer dizer que a condição `! isNaN(rota)` é `false` para esses valores de rota, então nunca entrará no `if`. A função `isNaN` avalia a string inteira - só porque tem um número nela, não quer dizer que toda a string também é um número.

Comment: @hkotsubo, Nao estou fazendo isso diretamente onde a rota esta... Eu faço outras coisas com a rota em outro component e dentro deste component eu preciso fazer isto acima...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da forma que você está fazendo realmente não vai funcionar, nos comentários outros colegas já explicaram o porque, então criei a função abaixo para tentar ajudar a resolver seu problema.

```js
function checkHasNumber(url) 
{
    var paths = url.split('/');
    var hasNumber = false;
    
    paths.forEach(function(value){
        if ("" != value && !isNaN(value)) {
            hasNumber = true;
        } 
    });
    
    return hasNumber;
}

var urlWithNumber = '/pessoa/editar/5';
var urlWithoutNumber = '/pessoa/editar/';


console.log(checkHasNumber(urlWithNumber));
console.log(checkHasNumber(urlWithoutNumber));
```

Comment: A partir da sua solução consegui fazer o que precisa, obrigado pela ajuda